# How to check the last char of a string and see its a blank space

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, char, lastindexof

How to check the last char of a string and see its a blank space? If its a blank space remove it?

Comment: Do you only want to remove the last char if blank, or all trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 60):

Specific for one space character:

```
if(MyString.EndsWith(" "))
    MyString = MyString.Substring(0, MyString.Length - 1);
```

or for any whitespace

```
MyString = MyString.TrimEnd();
```

Comment: Note typo: should be .Substring, not SubString.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Trim method of string class

Answer (score 3):

```
string Original= "I am on Test ";

string Temp = Original.Substring( Original.Length - 1 );
Original = Original.Remove( Temp.Trim().Length > 0 ? 0 : Original.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use special designed for it functions [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [`TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx), [`TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx):

```
var trimmedString = "this is my string with space at the end ".TrimEnd();
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this will remove ALL whitespace from the front and the end of the string, not just a single space from the end.

Comment: Updated to `TrimEnd` function :). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
string someString = "i will have some blank space at the end    ";
someString = someString.Trim(); //blank space now removed
```

It's worth noting that this will also remove blank spaces at the start of a string also

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Trim function with a char array as parameter to remove empty spaces and any other unwanted chars:

```
var formattedString = "formatted, but with empty values, , .";
var trimmedString = formattedString.TrimEnd(new char[] { ' ', ',', '.'});
// result = "formatted, but with empty values"
```

Answer (score 0):

another code for check the last char of a string is a blank char:

```
string text = "hello  ";
bool isBlank = text[text.Length -1].ToString().Trim().Length > 0 ? false : true;
```